# Python converting array to tuple

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, folium

I am trying to create a poly line using folium on map. It needs lat and longitude to convert to coordinates to show as line, I have written below code and it shows error as

```
Location should consist of two numerical values, but array([ 46.931625, -84.52694 ]) of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> is not convertible to float.
```

my code is

```
root = r'testfolder'
fstem = 'sample1'
fname = fstem+'.csv'
f = open(os.path.join(root,fname))
df= pd.read_csv(f)


points=[]
with open('testfolder/sample1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    df['lat'] = df['lat'].astype(float)
    df['long'] = df['long'].astype(float)
    for i in f:
        points.append(tuple(df[['lat', 'long']].values))
        ave_lat = sum(p[0] for p in points)/len(points)
        ave_lon = sum(p[1] for p in points)/len(points)
tuple(map(tuple, points))

my_map = folium.Map(location=[ave_lat, ave_lon], zoom_start=14)

#add a markers
for each in points:  
    folium.Marker(each).add_to(my_map)

#fadd lines
folium.PolyLine(points, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(my_map)
```

my data is as follows

```
event_id    long    lat
a   -84.52694   46.931625
a   -84.52684   46.931725
a   -94.25526333    42.71689167
a   -94.25524667    42.71689333
a   -94.25519167    42.716895
a   -94.25505167    42.71690833
b   -94.25531167    42.71687167
b   -94.255205  42.71689
b   -94.25515   42.7169
b   -94.25507   42.71691167
b   -94.25507167    42.71691167
b   -94.25511   42.716905
```

Please let me know how can I show it as tuple so that I can show it on map. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first block of your code should already give you a data frame

```py
root = r'testfolder'
fstem = 'sample1'
fname = fstem+'.csv'
f = open(os.path.join(root,fname))
df= pd.read_csv(f)
```

After you get the dataframe

```py
#convert the datatype of long and lat columns
df.long = df.long.astype(float)
df.lat = df.lat.astype(float)

#convert long and lat pairs in to a list of tuples
t = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(df.long,df.lat)]
```

That is all you need.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have many variables in the column event_id I have just shown a,b. How can I use that column to zip lat and long values

Comment: `a,b` in that list comprehension is not related to the event_id column. to avoid confusion i have renamed it to `i and j` now. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Is there a way I can group by a column that gives a list for each grouped event

Comment: Glad it worked. try `groupby` function. You can probably accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a generator expression and turn it into a tuple

```
t = tuple(e for e in array)
```